# RoR, updating elements in real-time, partials, iFrames or pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, live, pusher

I have an RoR app. It asks questions to people and I'd like to update that question, like every minute. I need the question and answers to be pushed in real time to every logged in users, and I'm using Pusher + Heroku for that matter.

Right now, I'm using pusher to send an ID to every one's view and then it deletes and displays a new iFrame with the new question every minute. The UI doesn't look great and it's a bit slow to update iFrames, I'm worrying it might be a bad practice. I don't know what better options are out there ? It'm thinking I could display a new partial, using escape_javascript, but it also seems weird to me and it means it has to be already stores in the controller ?

Or I could make a new javascript request but that makes a lot of data to store in a Hash and then display in HTML.

I don't know if anyone understands my problems but if you have suggestions or ideas, feel free to share.